# Why doesn't scaleY=-1 reflect text in AS3 code?

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to create text dynamically in AS3 and then reflect it. The most obvious way that comes to mind is to embed it in a sprite as a textfield and then reflect the sprite as follows:

```
var mySprite = new Sprite();
addChild(mySprite);
charField = new TextField()
charField.text = "a"
mySprite.addChild(charField)
mySprite.scaleY = -1
```

Bu nothing appears on the screen with this code. If I remove the `scaleY` command then the `a` appears as normal. Do I need to enable some property for the text to be manipulated?

Comment: You should probably embed the relevant font, appoint that font to your **TextField** via its **TextField.textFormat** property and set its **TextField.embedFonts** property to **true**.

Comment: I did try that, but it's not the issue. Without the scaling, it displays normally.

Comment: Will it show at scale 0.5?

Comment: Also, check this. While scaling, any display object scales around its (0,0), which is top left corner for the **TextField**. It is possible you just flip it over the top edge of the **Stage** so it is perfectly visible (in a logical sense) yet you cannot see it. Adjust your **MovieClip** coordinates to, say, (100, 100).

Comment: Still negative. The thing is that if I have a movieclip with text on stage (not dynamically in code) and apply the reflect by code, it works. Now I've found a solution by converting the text to a bitmap and then reflecting, but it's not a good solution. If it works in IDE it should work in code.

Comment: I wonder what will happen if you dynamically change the MC's `scaleY` with an enterframe listener, from 1 to 2 to -2 and backwards. It's possible that your TF's zero point is at an expected position but your wrapper sprite is at (0,0) thus with scaling your A would be moving first to the top and shrinking then hide up there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AS3 you can't transform a TextField like this if the font is **not** embedded. Same applies to rotation of a TextField by the way.
Simply setting the TextField's embedFonts property to true doesn't do it though as this won't actually embedd the font.

Try this:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        [Embed(systemFont="Arial",fontName="theFont",mimeType="application/x-font",fontWeight="normal",fontStyle="normal",advancedAntiAliasing="true",embedAsCFF="false")]
        private var theEmbeddedFont:Class;

        public function Main():void
        {
            if (stage)
                init();
            else
                addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
            format.font = "theFont";
            format.size = 44;

            var mySprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
            addChild(mySprite);
            var charField:TextField = new TextField();
            charField.defaultTextFormat = format;
            charField.embedFonts = true;
            charField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
            charField.wordWrap = false;
            charField.text = "a";
            mySprite.addChild(charField);

            mySprite.x = mySprite.y = 100;
            mySprite.scaleY = -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm new to embedding fonts. I tried to do it by clicking on the Embed Font button in the Character pane; the font's called now "Font 1" and I set the Linkage properties to Outline Format "DF3", linkage to "Export for ActionScript", and no sharing. It's not working. Do I have to embed the font dynamically as in your example, or there's some missing linkage property?

Comment: In this case **format.font = "theFont";** in my code above needs the Font Family name that can be seen in the Font Embedding dialog. Make sure you don't use the custom name which you can enter.